# Read/Write data from a Tabulated file format

Tags: python, file

So far in my python programs i use to store parameter/variable values(mostly configuration type values like width/heights/speed etc) in a text file,read them and use them.
But that is not aesthetically pleasing and i would prefer a file format that can be Tabulated. So what are my options available

Here is an example of current practice

[image: Here is an example of current practice]

And Here is what i am expecting.

[image: Here is what i am expecting]

Answer (score 1):

The [File Formats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileformats.html) section from the official documentation details all file formats supported within the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/).

For working with configuration files however, the new [tomllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tomllib.html) module is probably what you're after.

For example, your `config.toml` file might look something like this:

```
QR_pixel_density = 5
QR_border_size = 2
```

And to parse the `.toml` file you would just do:

```python
import tomllib
with open('config.toml', 'rb') as f:
    data = tomllib.load(f)

    print(data)
    # {'QR_pixel_density': 5, 'QR_border_size': 2}
```

After that just iterate over the dictionary to add the values into the GUI library you're using.

That being said, as the `tomllib` module is new in version 3.11, the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module is another option for Python 3.10 or earlier.